# what is the wrong in this *ngIf in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

What is wrong with this `*ngIf` directive

```
*ngIf="{{text}}=={{display.company}} ||{{text}}=={{display.field}}||{{text}}== 
{{display.sub_field}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to interpolate the values here with `{{  }}`, if they are defined on the component then the following should be fine.

```
*ngIf="text === display.company || text === display.field || text === display.sub_field"
```

This `*ngIf` would render into the view if either condition resulted in true.

[here is the documentation from Angular](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put the code in brackets(Interpolation)

```
<div *ngIf="text==display.company ||text==display.field||text== 
display.sub_field"> </div>
```

Comment: That does not compact it, it simply now checks that display.field and display.sub_field exist, which will most likely always result in true.

Comment: You're right I've tested it. Thanks for the info, I've edited my post